# Connecting to Teradata using Spark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, teradata

I am trying to connect to extract data from Teradata using Spark JDBC. I have created a "lib" directory on the main parent directory and placed the external Teradata jars and ran the sbt package. In addition,I am also providing the "--jars" option on my spark-shell command to provide the jar. However, when I run the spark-shell, it does not seem to find the class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool
```

However, when I do "jar tvf" on the jar file, I see the class. Somehow the Spark utility is unable to find the jar. Is there anything else I need to do so Spark could find it? Please help

Comment: Try adding that to your fat jar. That helped me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

This particular class `com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool` is in  `teradata-hadoop-connector.jar`

you can try to pass while submitting job like below example :

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath complete path of teradata-hadoop-connector.jar
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath complete path of teradata-hadoop-connector.jar
```

OR

import jars to both driver & executor. So, you need to edit `conf/spark-defaults.conf` adding both lines below.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath complete path of teradata-hadoop-connector.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath complete path of teradata-hadoop-connector.jar
```

- > NOTE : You can use [uber jar is also known as fat jar](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/) i.e. jar
  >   with dependencies. as well as alternative approach to avoid this kind
  >   of issue

Comment: is it working ? if yes can you vote-up/accept as owner or say this is my problem...  silence wont help!